# Why is this script printing to a file once and then rerunning and printing to console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have wrote code for both a bat file and a script that should use the bat to run the script. It runs the script correctly, but when I tried to get it to save it's output to a file, it runs the script twice, saving once to the file and once to the console. I would like some help figuring this out since I can't find any anywhere else.

Python Script-

```
import time
import sys
def goalshineinput(): #gets gfx names for print
    global gfxName #name of file without .dds
    gfxName = input("Enter GFX name exluding .dds or other file format. Type quit to quit.")
    if gfxName in {'quit', 'Quit', 'QUIT'}: #used to exit if quit is typed in
        exit('Goodbye')
    else:
        global gfxNameFile #name of file with .dds
        gfxNameFile = input("Enter GFX name including .dds or other file format. Type quit to quit.")
        confirmation()
def confirmation(): #confirms the user wants those, if not, restarts goalshineinput
    if gfxNameFile in {'Quit', 'quit', 'QUIT'}: #used to exit if quit is typed in
        exit('Goodbye')
    else:
        print(gfxName) #for testing, combine into complete sentence
        print(gfxNameFile) #for testing, combine into complete sentence
        sure = input('Are you sure? Y|N')
        if sure in {'y', 'Y'}:
            print('Confirmation Code Works!')
            goalshinework()
        elif sure in {'n', 'N'}:
            goalshineinput()
        else:
            print("Please Enter Y or N")
            time.sleep(2)
            confirmation()
def goalshinework(): #creates the thing to be printed
    print('SpriteType = {')
    print('\t''name = ''\"' + gfxName + '\"')
    print('\t''texturefile = ''\"''gfx/interface/goals/' + gfxNameFile + '\"')
    time.sleep(3)
goalshineinput()
```

Bat File-

```
@echo off
%1goalshine.py > output.txt
@py.exe goalshine.py %*
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually *run* it twice from the batch file, assuming you haven't provided an argument (the `%1`) to said batch file (comments added):

```
@echo off
%1goalshine.py > output.txt   - Run once, capturing output.
@py.exe goalshine.py %*       - Run again, output to screen.
pause
```

If you only want it to run once, you should probably remove one of those lines.